# Moshi Json annotation does not work with proguard

Tags: android, json, moshi

I followed https://github.com/square/moshi to add gradle dependency on moshi and proguard rules, then I write code to verify.

```
data class Car(
    @Json(name = "low_speed")  val lowSpeed: Int,
    @Json(name = "high_speed") val highSpeed: Int
)
```

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Car::class.java)

val json = "{\"low_speed\": 10, \"high_speed\": 20}"
val car = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)

if (car != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "${car.lowSpeed}+${car.highSpeed}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

when I run it in debug mode, it displayed "10+20", which is expected, but when I run in release mode (which has proguard enabled), I saw "0+0".

My proguard-rules.pro file:

```
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters     and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Common Stuff to Keep
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface

# OkHttp
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform

# okIo
-dontwarn okio.**

#moshi
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}

-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

# Enum field names are used by the integrated EnumJsonAdapter.
# values() is synthesized by the Kotlin compiler and is used by EnumJsonAdapter indirectly
# Annotate enums with @JsonClass(generateAdapter = false) to use them with Moshi.
-keepclassmembers @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
    **[] values();
}

#moshi-kotlin
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
```

my build.gradle dependency:

```
// moshi
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2")
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2")

// okhttp
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
```

I suppose I am missing something with moshi and proguard, but I really don't know what it is

Comment: can you share your module gradle file

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this? I'm encountering a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; Use the `@Keep` annotation to prevent minification of your target class.

My case was a little different from the one described by OP. My app was crashing when attempting to parse a JSON response with the moshi jsonAdapter.

```
val jsonAdapter = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build().let { moshi ->
    moshi.adapter(WeatherResponse::class.java)
}
```

...

```
val weatherResponse = response.body?.source()?.let { 
    jsonAdapter.nullSafe().fromJson(it) 
}
```

I resolved the issue by applying the `@Keep` annotation to the `WeatherResponse` class definition and all classes instantiated by `WeatherResponse`.

```
@Keep
data class Weather(
...
```

That seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This is the best answer so far

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = false)
```

**AND** add these lines to proguard:

```
-keepclassmembernames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    <fields>;
}
```

Credit -> https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/689